# How can I create a GTM data layer variable that pull the last item in a product array

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a eCommerce data layer that looks like this:

```
products: [
    {
      name: "T10 (Fri - Sun) Adult",
      id: "1123",
      price: "260",
      brand: "f1",
      category: "Austrian Formula 1 Grand Prix 2022",
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Red Bull: CDE (Fri - Sun) Adult",
      id: "1123",
      price: "251",
      brand: "f1",
      category: "Austrian Formula 1 Grand Prix 2022",
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Steiermark (South-West) (Fri - Sun) Adult",
      id: "1123",
      price: "420",
      brand: "f1",
      category: "Austrian Formula 1 Grand Prix 2022",
      quantity: 1
    }
  ]
```

When creating a data layer variable in GTM, I know I can create `products.0.name` and the result will be 'T10 (Fri - Sun) Adult.' Or `products.2.name` would result in 'Steiermark (South-West) (Fri - Sun) Adult.' But, if we assume I don't always know how many items will be in the product array, how can I create a variable that always pulls the final product (in the above example Steiermark (South-West) (Fri - Sun) Adult)?

**UPDATE**

I have tried products.slice(-1).name

[view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpRc3.png)

But that is giving a 'undefined' response

[view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MOM1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just use .slice(-1) on your array. Here:

[image]

You can also use .pop(), but pop mutates, therefore, no pops.

Comment: I have tried that in GTM, but the variable is just showing as undefined?

Comment: show your code. update the question.